# Optimizar mi codigo SQL Server (tabla temporal)

Tags: sql, sql-server

quisiera saber como podría optimizar mi código sql sin usar tabla temporal, ya que el software que ocupo para hacer reportes no funciona bien con ellas, mi código lo que hace es el "tiempo promedio por región desde la emisión del reporte hasta la fecha de la primera denuncia y de esta, hasta el ingreso al sistema".

```
select 'Reporte' tipo_doc, fecha_rep as Fecha_R, region, sy_id, fecha_rep as Fecha_A
into #Temporal
from Tabla1
where id in (select min(id)
             from Tabla1 
             where fecha_rep = '2019-01-01' group by sy_id, fecha_rep) 
and sy_id is not null
update #Temporal
set Fecha_A =  Tabla1.fecha_rep
from Tabla1
where denunciante_id = 7 
and #Temporal.sy_id = Tabla1.sy_id
select tipo_rep,  DATEDIFF( d, Fecha_R,Fecha_A) as diferencia, Region 
from #Temporal
union all
select 'Primera Denuncia' tipo_doc, DATEDIFF( d, fecha_recepcion, fecha_rep) as diferencia, Region
from Tabla1 where id in (select min(id) 
                         from Tabla1 
                         where fecha_rep = '2019-01-01' group by sy_id, fecha_rep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres utilizar tablas temporales puedes utilizar una variable de tipo tabla para insertar datos [TABLE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

un ejemplo con variable tabla:

```
declare @variableTabla as table 
(
   tipo_doc varchar(25), 
   fecha_rep datetime, 
   region varchar(25),
   sy_id int,  
   Fecha_A datetime
)

declare @minId int
select @minid = min(id)  from Tabla1 where fecha_rep = '2019-01-01' group by sy_id, fecha_rep


select 'Reporte' tipo_doc, fecha_rep as Fecha_R, region, sy_id, fecha_rep as Fecha_A
into @variableTabla
from Tabla1
where id  id = @minid -- elimino el in ya que min obtiene un dato
and sy_id is not null


select * from @variableTabla
```

Otra alternativa es utilizar [WITH CLAUSE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) que crea estos datos en memoria y solo existen en tiempo de ejecución de la consulta (al igual que una variable de tipo tabla)

un ejemplo con WITH seria:

```
;with table_ as (select 1 as algo)

select * from table
```

_

para un trozo de tu consulta, con with:

```
declare @minId int
select @minid = min(id)  from Tabla1 where fecha_rep = '2019-01-01' group by sy_id, fecha_rep


;with tusdatos as 
(
select 'Reporte' tipo_doc, fecha_rep as Fecha_R, region, sy_id, fecha_rep as Fecha_A
from Tabla1
where id = @minid -- elimino el in ya que min obtiene un dato
and sy_id is not null
)

select * from tusDatos
```